# Pandas is not importing my .csv file. how can i import my file?

Tags: dataframe

My pd.read_csv in Pandas is not importing my .csv file for visual representation.
i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('calorie.csv')
print(df)
```

What could be the problem?

```
File "c:\Users\aless\OneDrive\Desktop\pandas_project\main.py", line 31, in <module>    df=pd.read_csv('calorie.csv')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1024, in read_csv
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 618, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1618, in __init__
self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1896, in _make_engine
return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 93, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "parsers.pyx", line 581, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: The error tells you that there are no columns to parse. So, check your file has headers, and data, and is not otherwise corrupt. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.EmptyDataError.html

Comment: Also, please read [mre] and the provide test/example csv data in your question.